# Remove any interstitial ads that appear after the user has exited the app

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, admob, interstitial

[Thanks for submitting your app to Google Play. I reviewed "app", and had to reject it because it violates our interfering with apps and third-party ads policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still live on Google Play.

Here’s how you can submit your app for another review:

1)Remove any interstitial ads that appear after the user has exited the app, or after the user has pressed the back button to exit the app.
2)Read through the Interfering with Apps and Third-party Ads article for more details and examples.
3)Review your app to make sure it’s compliant with the Ads policy and all other policies listed in the Developer Program Policies. Remember that additional enforcement could occur if there are further policy issues with your apps.
4)Sign in to your Developer Console and submit your app.
If you’ve reviewed the ads policy and feel this rejection may have been in error, please reach out to our policy support team. One of my colleagues will get back to you within 2 business days.

I appreciate your support of Google Play!][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPNJy.jpg)

please i want to know what is the problem and the sollution
Thank you.

```
enter code here/** The Admob ad. */
private InterstitialAd interstitialAd = null;
public AdView adView = null;

public static MainActivity app;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    app = this;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // set view
    mGLSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);


    //Ads ----------------
    // Create the adView
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    //<!-- Ads Using Google Play Services SDK -->
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Add the adView to it
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    adView.setLayoutParams(params);

    layout.addView(mGLSurfaceView);
    layout.addView(adView);

    setContentView(layout);
    //New AdRequest
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    //-----------------------------------------------------Interstitial Add
    // Create an Interstitial ad.
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID);
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            interstitialAd.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Interstitial Ads loading failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    // Load the interstitial ad.
    //showInterstitialAds();

    //----------------------
    // set director
    CCDirector director = CCDirector.sharedDirector();
    director.attachInView(mGLSurfaceView);
    director.setAnimationInterval(1/60);

    // get display info
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    G.display_w = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    G.display_h = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    G.scale = Math.max(G.display_w/1280.0f, G.display_h/800.0f);
    G.width = G.display_w / G.scale;
    G.height = G.display_h / G.scale;

    // get data
    SharedPreferences sp = CCDirector.sharedDirector().getActivity().getSharedPreferences("GameInfo", 0);
    G.music = sp.getBoolean("music", true);
    G.sound = sp.getBoolean("sound", true);

    // create sound
    G.soundMenu = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.menu);
    G.soundMenu.setLooping(true);
    G.soundGame = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.game);
    G.soundGame.setLooping(true);
    G.soundCollide = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.collide);
    G.soundJump = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jump);
    G.soundLongJump = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.long_jump);
    G.soundSpeedDown = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.speed_down);
    G.soundSpeedUp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.speed_up);
    G.soundDirection = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.direction_sign);
    G.soundClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.menu_click);
    G.soundCollect = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.collect);
    G.bgSound = G.soundMenu;

    // show menu
    CCScene scene = CCScene.node();
    scene.addChild(new MenuLayer(true));
    director.runWithScene(scene);
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    if (adView != null) {
        adView.pause();
    }

    super.onPause();
    G.bgSound.pause();
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    if (adView != null) {
        adView.resume();
    }

    if( G.music ) G.bgSound.start();

    CCDirector.sharedDirector().onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    // Destroy the AdView.
    if (adView != null) {
        adView.destroy();
    }

    super.onDestroy();
    G.bgSound.pause();
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().end();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
    {
        CCDirector.sharedDirector().onKeyDown(event);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public void showInterstitialAds()
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            AdRequest interstitialAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            interstitialAd.loadAd(interstitialAdRequest);
        }
    });
}
```

}

[GameLayer.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfHiT.png)

Game over Method :
`public void gameOver()
    {
        _mask.runAction(CCFadeIn.action(0.6f));
        _msg.setTexture(CCTextureCache.sharedTextureCache().addImage("game/failed_logo.png"));
        _msg.runAction(CCSequence.actions(
            CCEaseElasticOut.action(CCMoveTo.action(0.6f, G.displayCenter()), 0.5f), 
            CCDelayTime.action(0.5f),
            CCEaseElasticIn.action(CCMoveTo.action(0.6f, CGPoint.ccp(-G.width*0.5f, G.height*0.5f)), 0.5f), 
            CCCallFunc.action(this, "restart")));

```
    MainActivity.app.showInterstitialAds();
}`
```

Comment: when is gameover method called? Which method?

Comment: public void gameOver()
 {
  _mask.runAction(CCFadeIn.action(0.6f));
  _msg.setTexture(CCTextureCache.sharedTextureCache().addImage("game/failed_logo.png"));
  _msg.runAction(CCSequence.actions(
   CCEaseElasticOut.action(CCMoveTo.action(0.6f, G.displayCenter()), 0.5f), 
   CCDelayTime.action(0.5f),
   CCEaseElasticIn.action(CCMoveTo.action(0.6f, CGPoint.ccp(-G.width*0.5f, G.height*0.5f)), 0.5f), 
   CCCallFunc.action(this, "restart")));
  
  MainActivity.app.showInterstitialAds();
 }